# beam yaml - add timestamp to csv file

Tags: apache-beam

i am creating a beam pipeline using beam yaml.
i have a csv table including a timestamp value, and would like to use it for a windowing aggregation.
not sure what is the right syntax for using this timestamp as the row's timestamp for windowing purposes.

my csv file is:

```
id,firstname,age,country,profession,timestamp
5,Natka,26,France,doctor,2024-01-03T13:30:10
10,Orelia,31,Germany,police officer,2024-01-03T13:30:12
1,Reeba,58,Belgium,unemployed,2024-01-03T13:30:15
7,Elvira,39,Italy,doctor,2024-01-03T13:30:21
3,Meg,11,France,unemployed,2024-01-03T13:30:27
6,Aurore,32,Italy,police officer,2024-01-03T13:30:42
11,Theodora,16,Italy,unemployed,2024-01-03T13:30:37
4,Rani,53,Spain,doctor,2024-01-03T13:30:58
9,Lesly,35,Spain,firefighter,2024-01-03T13:30:49
2,Maud,45,Spain,firefighter,2024-01-03T13:30:45
8,Asia,10,Belgium,doctor,2024-01-03T13:30:34
```

and the pipeline:

```
pipeline:
  type: chain
  transforms:
    - type: ReadFromCsv
      config:
        path: data/people.csv     

    # Should probably add a transform to handle timestamp issue

    - type: WindowInto
      windowing:
        type: fixed
        size: 10
    - type: Combine
      config:
        group_by: country
        combine:
          total:
            value: age
            fn: sum
    - type: LogForTesting
    - type: WriteToJson
      config:
        path: ~/out.json
options:
  yaml_experimental_features: Combine
```

Thanks!

Comment: As a follow-up question, I am trying to implement it by defining a custom transform, but not sure about the python syntax (usually this is done on the same class)
Any guidance on creating a custom provider in beam yaml would be appreciated :)